# Linq Passing table as an object to Table<t>

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following methods

```
static DataContext dc;

public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable1()
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<Table1>().Count();
}

public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable2()
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<Table2>().Count();
}
```

and son on.

i want to have a method that will accept the table as argument :

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable1(Table<t> myTable)
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<myTable>().Count();
}
```

how can i do that ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your [method generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable<T>(Table<T> myTable)
   where T : class
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<T>().Count();
}
```

In the above example, you're not actually using `myTable`. If you don't need it, you can remove it:

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable<T>()
   where T : class
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<T>().Count();
}

// call these methods like:
GetTotalRecordsForTable(myTable); // T as Table1 is inferred
GetTotalRecordsForTable<Table1>(); // T as Table1 is explicitly specified
```

Comment: I believe that is Linq to SQL, so added required constraint on generic type parameter

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks, I hadn't noticed [that constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220(v=vs.110).aspx). I added it to my other method, too (looks like it's needed in both places).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this?

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable1<T>()
{
  DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
  return dc.GetTable<T>().Count();
}
```

You do not even need the argument since it looks like you just want to pass in the generic type to retrieve the data. You can add a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to limit what the `T` can be, also

Answer (score 0):

Use generics, just like the `GetTable` method itself does:

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable<TTable>()
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext ();
    return dc.GetTable<TTable>().Count();
}
```

You can add a generic constraint to limit the generic argument to some interface, if all of your tables implement one:

```
public static Int32 GetTotalRecordsForTable<TTable>()
    where TTable : ITable
```

Then call it much like you would call `GetTable`:

```
var count = GetTotalRecordsForTable<Table1>();
```